# Calculating CRC using Python zlib.crc32 function

Tags: python, crc

I created a list of size 100 and populated the array with 8bit data in python using the following code and I want to calculate the CRC value using the zlib.crc32() function.

```
Init_RangenCrc8 = []
for i in range(0,100):
    Init_RangenCrc8.append(random.randrange(0, 255, 1))

crc8_python = zlib.crc32(Init_RangenCrc8, 0xFFFF)
```

When I return and print the crc8_python, I am not getting any value back.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your code looks a little strange. `Init_RangenCrc8 = []` should be before the `for` loop, shouldn't it? The indentation doesn't look right.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> help(zlib.crc32)
Help on built-in function crc32 in module zlib:

crc32(...)
    crc32(string[, start]) -- Compute a CRC-32 checksum of string.

    An optional starting value can be specified.  The returned checksum is
    a signed integer.
>>> zlib.crc32("".join(chr(random.randrange(0,255)) for _ in xrange(100)))
333158331
```

**EDIT:** code that uses the start value `0xFFFF`:

```
>>> text = "".join(chr(random.randrange(0,255)) for _ in xrange(100))

>>> zlib.crc32(text)
-964269250

>>> zlib.crc32(text, 0xFFFF)
2057263175
```

Comment: You've missed the `0xFFFF` start value. Nevertheless +1.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Also, do you want a crc32 for each element of the list, or a single crc32 for the string comprised of each char in the list?

Comment: The first argument has to be a string because that is how the API is defined.  As far as the error, you need to `import zlib` and `import random` for this solution to work, which is the right solution given your description.

Comment: @Chris Row; you've got to import zlib first to use the contents of the module. Also "why does the first argument have to be a string?" -- that's what the documentation says the function takes. If it's documented to take a data type, it's probably not going to work correctly if you give it an input of a different type.